# yarn dev command not working on windows 10

Tags: windows, npm, yarnpkg, nuxt.js

I know my question has been asked alot but nothing seems to work for me. I created a new nuxt project, whenever i try to start it with `yarn dev` it keeps giving me this error: `yarn is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Even after setting the variabeles in windows to the correct path of yarn it is still not working for me. I have had this problem for months now, but i keep procrastinating to fix it. I feel like asking this question is my last hope of fixing this problem. I really hope someone can help me with my problem.

Comment: did you installed yarn.msi, if not download from here https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#windows-stable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yarn is not globally installed. Run `npm install yarn -g` to install yarn globally

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, your win10's PATH variable isn't correct.Try reinstall yarn.